# Export all source code with gradle in one file

Tags: gradle, export

I really love to play on site like *coding-game* but i have a problem: I also really love my IDE.

Do you have an export method of all my source code from multiple file in a single output file source code with gradle ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible because of the SourceSet where Gradle holds the sources is just a FileCollection. The following snippet does what you want, you may need adjust the output file formatting.

```
task exportCode {
  def outputFile = file("$buildDir/allSources.txt")
  outputs.file  outputFile
  doLast {
    sourceSets.main.allJava.collect { sourceFile ->
      outputFile << sourceFile.text
    }
  }
}
```

`sourceSets.main.allJava` returns a FileCollection which lists all your main sources. If you need also test sources use `sourceSets.test.allJava`   (more general: `sourceSets.SOURCESET_NAME.allJava`)